# Local Dynamodb Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, local

As the title speaks, is there a way to visualize data in local dynamodb like how it is on AWS Console? This seems to be one of the drawback to me because using localhost:8000/shell (default endpoint) and doing scans requiring the setup of the attributes and etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the [NoSQL Workbench for DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/workbench.html). It can [connect to DynamoDB Local](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/nosql-workbench-for-amazon-dynamodb-adds-support-for-dynamodb-local/).

[image]

Comment: This is quite comprehensive! Just noticed it's publish in the aws docs itself, not that i wasnt searching but the keywords often not matched to anything related

Answer (score 1):

1. [Dynobase](https://dynobase.dev/) is good (however it is not free - at least not forever...).
2. [DynamoDB Admin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb-admin) is very simple, but its better than nothing.

e.g. simple docker-compose line:

```
   dynamo-admin:
    image: instructure/dynamo-local-admin
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
      - "8042:8042"
    environment:
      DYNAMO_ENDPOINT: http://dynamodb:8000
```

Comment: yeapz. I came across dynamodb-admin right after posting this question lol answered in the post as well but it's great indeed

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb-admin

I have then came across with this webapp that visualize dynamodb data across platform. Working quite well especially if you're developing on Serverless Framework.

tldr;

```
npm i dynamodb-admin
DYNAMO_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:8000 dynamodb-admin
```

(assume you are running local dynamodb on default port 8000)

Browse http://localhost:8001